# Dynamic Code Evaluation: Code Injection in JSTL <c:out value="${searchVal != null ? searchVal :''}"/>

Tags: jsp, struts2, jstl, jsp-tags, owasp

I have Jsp and Struts 2 based application where we have used jstl to render the output. Now if in any of the get APIs i am giving the request param as jsp expression. For eg :

```
http://localhost:8090/inputParam.do?searchVal=${pageContext.servletContext.serverInfo}
```

and the request param searchVal is as it is returned by the controller which is rendered on the JSP as

```
var gText = '<c:out value="${searchVal != null ? searchVal :''}"/>';
```

The above line is actually dynamically rendering the searchVal jsp expresion and giving the output as `JBoss Web/7.5.28.Final-redhat-1` 
and the vulnerability scanner is considering the above behavior as vulnerability.

Hi can i fix this?

Comment: You're rendering raw data into JavaScript meaning there's a direct path to JS injection. Even if it contained a single quote it would break your JS. At the very least you'd need to escape all quote styles.

Comment: @DaveNewton So in that case if I will just write as <c:out value="${searchVal != null ? searchVal :''}"/> without assigning it to any js variable then in this case it will not result into any vulnerability?

Comment: It depends on context. If it's JS it doesn't matter if it's assigned or not. If it's in HTML then normal tag escaping applies.

Comment: I am not sure why this question is marked as duplicate. @DaveNewton can you please give an example what all things should be escaped in the above example.